# Deutsche Bahn - Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket and ICE

Tags: trains, tickets, budget, germany

I'm going to Germany, I found out that train travel will be cheaper with Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket for 44 EUR.

My question is: can I travel with this ticket by ICE and OE trains? I need to go through whole country at once. If not, is there any option to search only regional trains at DBahn(DB) site?

Comment: During the week-end, the Schönes-Wochenende-Ticket offers essentially the same (actually a bit more as it's valid for local transit trains – S-Bahn – and also includes some trips to neighbouring countries, which is not the case for the Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket) and is cheaper.

Comment: On the other hand, you don't really want to go the whole way non-stop with only regional trains. That's hardly possible in a day. I just checked Munich to Kiel with only Nahverkehr, and it takes about 18 hours.

Comment: @simbabque some people have a lot more time than money, or just like trains.

Comment: One final remark, where have you seen a train marked OE? If that's an [ODEG train](http://odeg.de/tarifuebersicht/db-angebote/), then the Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket is indeed valid on that train. It should show up as "local transport" in search results on Bahn.de.

Comment: @phoog: Time has a natural upper boundary of 23 hours (in practice, less than that, because there is much less service during the night). Beyond that, you'll need an extra ticket for the next day, which somewhat compensates for the financial advantage. As for liking trains - indeed, but when comparing what traveling is like on long distance trains and regional trains, respectively, one could say "not all trains are equal" ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper sure.  My point was just that simbabque's "you don't really want" comment assumes something about costs and benefits that is probably true for most people, even a large majority, but likely not to be true for *all* people.

Comment: Thanks guys for answers and sorry for late reply.
So we decided on Schönes-Wochenende-Ticket for 44 EUR (2 person), and spent whole day (8.20-20.15+3h outside Germany) in travel, but luckly german trains are comfortable. As @phoog said, I'm student living in Poland, so I have lot more time than money, especially when you look at EUR/PLN rate.

Comment: @Relaxed - if I remember well I saw OE in Sachsen, and it classified to Schönes-Wochenende-Ticket.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, you cannot take an ICE and yes, there is an option to search only regional trains on Bahn.de (checkbox "Nur Nahverkehr" – in the new version, it only appears after clicking in one of the boxes of the search form – or "Local transport").

A few other tips:

- During the week-end, the Schönes-Wochenende-Ticket offers essentially the same (actually a bit more as it includes more trips to neighbouring countries and is also valid for local commuter trains – S-Bahn – and before 9 AM, which is not the case for the Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket) and is cheaper.
- If you are on your own and planning a one-way trip, do check the [Sparpreis Finder](https://www.bahn.de/p_en/view/booking/tickets-and-seats/sparpreisfinder.shtml) too, you can sometimes find cheap ICE fares that are similar or not much higher than the Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket, for a much higher comfort. For a small group or a day trip (return on the same day), nothing comes close to the Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket, Schönes-Wochenende-Ticket or Länder-Ticket, pricewise, but for one person it's not always the case.
- Finally, travelling long distances by chaining regional trains can take a long time. If you mostly care about saving money and would consider something else than the train, long-distance buses and ride sharing (*Mitfahrgelegenheit*) can also be cheap and would not necessarily be slower (but slightly less comfortable in my opinion).

Comment: Use this https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/en for english user interface

Comment: The *Schönes-Wochenende-Ticket * has another very useful property: it is valid before 9:00 (which is not the case for the Ländertickets and Quer-Durchs-Land-Ticket)

Comment: @Chieron I forgot about that, good tip, I added it to the answer, thanks!

Comment: I agree with the buses. but somtime they can come late. it happens very often. but i take the bus everyweekend Hannover to göttingen, it takes a little longer. maybe 10 minutes longer!! :) ( let me know if this comment doesnt belong here i will delete it)

Comment: The busses depend on traffic, so they are usually never 100%ly on time. They are either too early or too late. Additionally I feel like companies like FlixBus are raising their prices drastically so that there is less to none difference in price compared to train.

Comment: @Marv they are building a de-facto monopoly right now. First MeinFernBus aquired Flixbus, now they merged with Postbus (which was ADAC Postbus before). The other ones are far away from the same level of service. So now they control the market.

Comment: @Marv I rarely use any of this and would go for a long-distance train myself but if you are looking for the cheapest solution and are ready to endure a full day of travel on regional trains (what the question is about), I am not sure that even one or two hours of difference compared to the published schedule matter all that much.

Comment: @Relaxed one or two hours actually is massive. It tends to be between -15 and +45 minutes for me usually. When it starts being later than that, I would look for a replacement bus. As long as it is the same company they usually let you change busses for free (if there is enough space obviously)

Comment: @simbabque I am aware of that, was more like a status of the current situation. It is a shame though, busses were like the alternative to the pricy trains and now there is not much of a difference.

Comment: @Marv Yes, that's why I took that as an example... If you are considering regional trains like the OP, you propose putting up with a full day of travel to save a little (simbabque's Munich-Kiel example was 18 hours vs. 7 with regular long-distance trains) so it doesn't matter much one way or the other and there is no reason to obsess with the published schedule. The bus is probably faster to begin with and you will get there eventually.

Comment: At least if there is a direct bus. Then all you need to do is sit on the bus. They usually have high quality Internet that's fast enough for streaming music and chatting (or coding) and a good selection of current movies. The bathroom on the train is a bit nicer, but the seats on the bus are more roomy. The bus also has power sockets for every two seats while regional trains have from two per car to none. But at least on the train you get to walk around, and switch trains and stuff.

Comment: @simbabque "seats on the bus are more roomy": Very interesting.  That has certainly not been my experience with trains and buses in other countries.

Comment: @phoong in Germany the Flixbus, MeinFernBus and Postbus long distance busses are all very new. There is more legroom than in the ICE, especially the ICE 3. You can also move the inner seats about 15cm into the corridor. On the train you can't. But then in the ICE you can put the seat back and the surface of the seat to the front to lay back without the back moving towards the person behind you. On the bus, you get squished. I guess it's all compromises.

Comment: And if you are only in a single *Bundesland* you can also take a much cheaper *Länderticket*. (I think, Thuringia, Saxony and Saxony-Anhalt have a single ticket between the three of them.)

Comment: @Jan [Yes, that's true](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/angebot/regio/laender_tickets.shtml).

Comment: @Relaxed, I've a one more question - you wrote "During the week-end, the Schönes-Wochenende-Ticket [...] includes more trips to neighbouring countries".
I'm not sure if I understood correctly. Can I travel dbahn trains outside Germany during weekend with this ticket? There is connection between Dresden-Wroclaw (Breslau) which mostly operator is dbahn. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: @Szkaplerny I don't think so, you can't take any DB train in Poland. [The full list is here](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/mdb/bahnintern/angebotsberatung/regio/laender-tickets/pdfs/mdb_233174_1016_geltungsbereich_schoenes-wochenende-ticket.pdf) (scroll down to section 5) but it's always local trains, mostly to border towns and I don't see Wroclaw in there.

Comment: @Relaxed - this link explains everything. Thanks, need to save this.

Comment: @Chieron The Ländertickets and the Quer-durchs-Land-Ticket are valid before 9:00 PM on *weekends* as well. It is not an argument to buy the Schönes Wochenende Ticket